# How to not have to write java.lang each time I make a string?

Tags: java

Why do I have to write `java.lang` each time I want a `String`?

```
public class String {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        java.lang.String text = "Hello";
        java.lang.String blank = " ";
        java.lang.String name = "name"; // <-- these aren't 
        String greeting = text + blank + name; // <-- this is an error
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your class is named `String` (so it shadows `java.lang.String`). Rename your class to something else. Like `MyString`.

```
public class MyString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "Hello";
        String blank = " ";
        String name = "name";
        String greeting = text + blank + name;
        System.out.println(greeting);
    }
}
```

**or** use<sup>1</sup> a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) like

```
String text = "Hello";
String blank = " ";
String name = "name";
System.out.println(new StringBuilder(text).append(blank).append(name));
```

<sup>1<sub>Java `String` is *immutable*, while `StringBuilder` is mutable. For concatenation, I would thus prefer `StringBuilder`.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

String is built in class in java you can not define classes that are built in the java.

if you wish to define make if MyString or anything like that 
and the java.lang package is by default imported in every java file so don;t wory about importing it again and again.

hope it will work for you

```
`public class abc //anything but NOT STRING cuase it is built in
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String a1="hello";
        String a2="there";
        String a3="how";
        String a4="are";
        String a5="you";
        System.out.println(a1+a2+a3+a4+a5);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Of course you can define classes that have the same name as Java core classes (as long as the package is different). It might be a bad idea but you can do it.